# How is this particular arithmetic expression called?

Tags: terminology

A normal arithmetic expression looks like this, right?:

```
3 + 5 * 3 + 14 / 7
```

The same expression written in Scheme looks like this:

```
(+ 3 (* 5 3) (/ 14 7) )
```

How do I call it? Is there a name for such an unusual way of writing an arithmetic expression?

The thing is, I've written a program that evaluates such Scheme'ish expressions and now I don't know how do I describe what it does. Thanks!

**Edit: Rob Arthan correctly commented that it was S-expression. Someone put it as an answer so I can mark it solved!**

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation.

Comment: Looks like [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation)

Comment: Put is as an answer so I can mark this question solved.

Comment: The brackets are useless.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, that's what Lisp uses! Put it as an answer!

Comment: @Eclipse Sun:you might like to review your comment in the light of my answer.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes. In this case, the brackets are not redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These things are called [S-expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression). It is not the same as Polish notation: in Polish notation, you don't need brackets because each operator has a known number of operands. Something like (+ 1 2 3) is a perfectly good S-expression and evaluates to 6 in Scheme.

Comment: And, I'd note, that not all S-expressions will give valid calculable expressions. So this is an S-expression implementation of prefix notation.